# C# How to call MVC Controller function by using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this at my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteUser(UserViewModel viewModel)
{
}
```

I have this at my cshtml:

```
<input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Delete" />
```

I have this at my js file:

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function (e) {

});
```

How do I call controller function from js file?

Comment: include  `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the form that you are posting

Comment: @PrashanthBenny How is this a duplicate of a specific antiforgery question if OP seems to have no idea how to post to a controller in the first place or ha sspecified a form is being used? How did the question become about that? I'm sure it is a duplicate of some sort but not of that question as far as I can see. - Sorry if I missed something.

Comment: The answers to the question mentioned above  seems to answer this question too. maybe i am wrong... :)

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Very indirectly as OP of other question already knew how to call actions from javascript and had a totally different issue. Assuming OP of this question is new to ajax and calling into controllers from JavaScript, given the question, the marked duplicate would be more than overwhelming...just saying, a more fitting duplicate would be more along the lines of ► [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162760/how-to-call-an-mvc-action-using-only-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162760/how-to-call-an-mvc-action-using-only-javascript)

Comment: @Fran but this one has more possibility of breaking because of this guy `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` right? But the question seems to be the other way! `Confused!` :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("Controller/CreateUser", dataToPost)
            .done(function(response, status, jqxhr){ 
                // this is the "success" callback
            })
            .fail(function(jqxhr, status, error){ 
                // this is the ""error"" callback
            });
```

or

```
var data = {
        username: $('#username').val().trim(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Controller/CreateUser",
    content: "application/json;",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(d) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

ps: compose the data object according to the UserViewModel properties.

Comment: I hit error : POST localhost:56110/user/controller/DeleteUser

Comment: I left Controller because I didn`t know the name of your controller. Just remove it and put the right controller name

Answer (score 0):

Inside the button click, execute ajax request

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function (e) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'controller/DeleteUser',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
        //html content
      },
    });
 }
```

Comment: Why do you set `data:"Json"` ? Maybe you mean `dataType`. `dataType` is the type of data you are expecting from the server. `data` property is the data you will send to server.

Comment: sorry it should be datatype

Comment: I hit error :

POST http://localhost:56110/user/controller/DeleteUser 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai The `dataType: json` is not the c# User class. It can be set to: xml/html/script/json/jsonp/text. Chech the Jquery ajax function for more info.

Comment: @Enix, you should replace `controller` with your `controller` name.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to access any controller method using ajax post method.

> As here I'm getting states as per selected country using
>   'RegionesController' method name 'GetStates' also here I'm passing
>   CountryId to get states as per this id.

**EX:**

```
function GetStates() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: abp.appPath + 'Regiones/GetStates?CountryId=' + $("#ddlCountry").val(),
        success: function (result) {
           //return data or object
        },
        error: function (err) {
            abp.notify.info(err.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```